# How to make eslint work for the whole directory in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, lint

I am trying to check linting errors in my node js application and then start the server.

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "eslint **/*.js",
    "start": "node .",
    "posttest": "npm run lint && nsp check"
  }
```

npm run pretest never checks the whole directory set . It i do a npm run lint . It gives me weird errors like

```
Cannot find module 'eslint-config-medikoo-es5'
Referenced from: /home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/server/node_modules/es5-ext/package.json
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-medikoo-es5'
Referenced from: /home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/server/node_modules/es5-ext/package.json
    at ModuleResolver.resolve (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
    at resolve (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:515:25)
    at load (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:532:26)
    at configExtends.reduceRight (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:424:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (native)
    at applyExtends (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:408:28)
    at Object.load (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:566:22)
    at loadConfig (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:63:33)
    at getLocalConfig (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:130:29)
    at Config.getConfig (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:260:26)
```

and if i install that dependency i am stuck at this

```
Cannot find module '@ljharb/eslint-config'
Referenced from: /home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/qs/.eslintrc
Error: Cannot find module '@ljharb/eslint-config'
Referenced from: /home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/server/node_modules/express/node_modules/qs/.eslintrc
    at ModuleResolver.resolve (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
    at resolve (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:515:25)
    at load (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:532:26)
    at configExtends.reduceRight (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:424:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (native)
    at applyExtends (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:408:28)
    at Object.load (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:566:22)
    at loadConfig (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:63:33)
    at getLocalConfig (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:130:29)
    at Config.getConfig (/home/rahul/DSP/dsp-api/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:260:26)
```

Please help

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're linting the files in `node_modules` as well, which you shouldn't do.

You should ignore this folder following [these instructions](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#ignoring-files-from-linting).
Also, you should change your NPM `pretest` script to match the `lint` script. I would suggest to change it to `npm run lint`.

> ESLint supports `.eslintignore` files to exclude files from the linting process when ESLint operates on a directory. Files given as individual CLI arguments will be exempt from exclusion. The `.eslintignore` file is a plain text file containing one pattern per line. It can be located in any of the target directory’s ancestors; it will affect files in its containing directory as well as all sub-directories. Here’s a simple example of a `.eslintignore` file:
>
> ```
> node_modules
> ```

Comment: I tried to add a ignore files but still the same error

Comment: Updated answer with the suggestion to change the NPM `pretest` script

Answer (score 1):

> You can add a `.eslintignore` file and inside just add the following
>   line `node_modules`.

This will ignore the files inside node_modules.